# Problem with htaccess (images)

Tags: php, .htaccess, image

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9/_]+)/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)_([0-9a-zA-Z_]+).([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$ imgsize.php?&w=$2&h=$3img=$1/$4.$5 [L]
```

path to file:

```
/imgsize.php?w=200&h=100&img=uploads/elvita.jpg

/uploads/100x110_elvita.jpg
```

why its not working? :(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you got the answer, but I think the period in the first part of the rule needs to be escaped. So, for instance: .

Answer (score 0):

Just filling in on @Patrick's answer:
`RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9/_]+)/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)_([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)\.([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$ imgsize.php?&w=$2&h=$3img=$1/$4.$5 [L]`